# Problem moving from itext 7.0.4 to 7.1.11

Tags: itext

I have some code written in itext 7 that loads large PDF with IRandomAccessSource

```
IRandomAccessSource rdSource = null;
File pdf = new File(folder, getFilename());
rdSource = new RandomAccessSourceFactory().createBestSource(pdf.getCanonicalPath());

pdfReader = new PdfReader(rdSource, null);
PdfDocument doc = new PdfDocument(pdfReader); // --> Throws NullPointerException with 7.1.11
```

If PdfDocument doc = new PdfDocument(pdfReader) is called I get a NullPointerException since I changed the Maven Dependencies from 7.0.4 to 7.1.11

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.itextpdf.kernel.pdf.PdfDocument.open(PdfDocument.java:1867)
    at com.itextpdf.kernel.pdf.PdfDocument.<init>(PdfDocument.java:252)
    at com.itextpdf.kernel.pdf.PdfDocument.<init>(PdfDocument.java:234)
    at pdfTextExtractor.ValidateSendung.execute(ValidateSendung.java:68)
    at pdfTextExtractor.TestValidateSendunge.test2(TestValidateSendunge.java:36)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:50)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:325)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:78)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:57)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:89)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:41)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:541)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:763)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:463)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:209)
```

Maven Dependencies are:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.itextpdf</groupId>
    <artifactId>kernel</artifactId>
    <version>7.1.11</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.itextpdf</groupId>
    <artifactId>io</artifactId>
    <version>7.1.11</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.itextpdf</groupId>
    <artifactId>layout</artifactId>
    <version>7.1.11</version>
</dependency>
```

Any hint, why this happens with the new Version? 
Thank you

Regards Michel

```
Method PDFDocument.open --> Crashes on 
 memoryLimitsAwareHandler = reader.properties.memoryLimitsAwareHandler;
as reader.properties is null

   protected void open(PdfVersion newPdfVersion) {
        this.fingerPrint = new FingerPrint();

        try {
            EventCounterHandler.getInstance().onEvent(CoreEvent.PROCESS, properties.metaInfo, getClass());
            if (reader != null) {
                if (reader.pdfDocument != null) {
                    throw new PdfException(PdfException.PdfReaderHasBeenAlreadyUtilized);
                }
                reader.pdfDocument = this;
                memoryLimitsAwareHandler = reader.properties.memoryLimitsAwareHandler;
```

Comment: Can you share that large PDF?

Comment: Hi Amedee.. the Problem happens on any size since the change.. I use a small 600 KB PDF. the ones I use contain customer data. so cannot share.. will check if it also happens on other PDF's.. Then I can share one.

Comment: Hi Amedee I added a test PDF to https://github.com/michelriondel/git-for-sharing/blob/master/Test.pdf The problem occurs on any PDF.

Comment: Hi Michael I don't have time to look at it now but I hope that with your code example + file someone else can help you out.

Comment: Please share the full stack trace of the `NullPointerException`.

Comment: Hi Amedee I have added the Stacktrace, but it's not realy chatty :-(

Comment: the problem is, that the reader.properties attribute is null:

Answer (score 2):

Obviously the ReaderProperties need to be passed in the new Version. 
I changed the code to

```
pdfReader = new PdfReader(rdSource, new ReaderProperties());
```

And now it works.. 
How can this be, that this worked in V.7.0.4 and now it changed with 7.1.11?

Anyhow: Problem solved

Regards

Comment: Evidently, you have to read all the documentation (if exists) and be a guru with the library to use it. This is realy bad example of library maintanance. Thanks pal.